# Sumar un array - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

tengo un array que me trae de la base de datos dos registros cuyo valor es : 5 y 10 , estos datos vienen como string y los convierto a números y **necesito que se sumen**  pero no me esta sumando solo me esta mostrando los dos números.

```js
 //traigo de la base de datos la data del campo valor y me carga y los paso a entero
 const ok =  data.map(name => (  
         
      
          parseInt( name.valor )
         
      ))

// aqui hago la suma pero no me esta sumando solo me muestra los numeros que encontro en base de datos
         const suma = [ok].reduce((a,b) => a + b);
         console.log(suma);
```

Answer (score 0):

cambie todo el algoritmo mencionado por :

```js
const total = data.map((data) => Number(data.valor)) .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); 
        console.log(total);
```